# How to integrate Angular2 with OSGi?

Tags: angular, osgi

There is a ng1 bundle in OSGi, but no ng2. I want to integrate ng2 with OSGi. Is there anyway to load NgModule dynamic in different bundles?

Any idea is appreciated. Thank you!

PS: I have heard about AOT, maybe this is a possible way.